# Java String Analysis for complete string regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a tool like Java String Analysis (JSA) that could sum up a string as a regex. I have tried to do that with JSA, but there I need to search for a specific method like StringBuffer.append or other string operations.

I have strings like that:

```
        StringBuilder test=new StringBuilder("hello ");
        boolean codition=false;
        if(codition){
            test.append("world");
        }
        else{
            test.append("other world");
        }
        test.append(" so far");
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
            test.append(" again hello");
        }

        // regularExpression = "hello (world| other world) so far( again hello)*"
```

And my JSA implementation looks like that so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringAnalysis.addDirectoryToClassPath("bootstrap.jar");

        StringAnalysis.loadClass("org.apache.catalina.loader.Extension");
        List<ValueBox> list = StringAnalysis.getArgumentExpressions("<java.lang.StringBuffer: java.lang.StringBuffer append(java.lang.String)>", 0);

        StringAnalysis sa = new StringAnalysis(list);
        for (ValueBox e : list) {
            Automaton a = sa.getAutomaton(e);
            if (a.isFinite()) {
                Iterator<String> si = a.getFiniteStrings().iterator();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (si.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append((String) si.next());
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            } else if (a.complement().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(e.getValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println("common prefix:" + a.getCommonPrefix());
            }
        }

    }
```

I would be very appreciated for any help with the JSA tool or for a hint to another tool. My biggest issue with the regex the control flow structure around the string constant.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sum up a string as a regex"?

Comment: I mean that like in the example above: There I have several string constants and string variables, which are scattered around the control flow graph and I want a representation like in the comment. If two or more strings are in an if-block then I want the strings in the if-part to be in front of the |-or-regex-sign and the ones in the else-part after it. And so on. Does it answer your question? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Could you specify the input and the output datas of your algorithm?

Comment: The input is a jar file like: bootstrap.jar above and the output should be a regex like the comment in the first code snippet.

Comment: Your sample output is incorrect. Since `codition` is always false, the regex should be `hello other world so far( again hello)*`, or even `'hello other world so far( again hello){' + args.length + '}'`

Comment: For the beginning it would be enough to get an over approximate version of the example regex. I want to have it in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a tool which yields you a regex out of the box.

But since you have issues with the CFG I would recommend you to write a static analysis tailored to your problem. You could use a static analysis/bytecode framework like [OPAL](http://opal-project.de/) (Scala) or [Soot](http://sable.github.io/soot/) (Java). You will find tutorials on each project page.

Once you set it up you can load the target jar. You should be able to leverage the control flow of the program then like in the following example:

```
1 public static void example(String unknown) {
2   String source = "hello";
3   if(Math.random() * 20 > 5){
4       source += "world";
5   } else {
6       source += "unknown";
7   }
8   source += unknown;
  }
```

If your analysis finds a String or StringBuilder which is initialized you can start to build your regular expression. Line number two for instance would bring your regex to "hello". If you meet a conditional in the control flow of your program you can analyze each path and combine them via an "|" later on.

Then branch: "world"    (line 4) 
Else branch: "unknown"  (line 6)

This could be summarized at line 7 to (world)|(unknown) and append to the regex before the conditional.

If you encounter a variable you either can trace it back if you do an inter-procedural analysis or you have to use the wildcard operator ".*" otherwise.

Final regex: "hello((world)|(unknown)).*"

I hope that this leads you to your solution you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Lucene has some  [tools](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/Automaton.html) around finite state automata and regular expressions. In particular, you can take the [union](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/Automaton.html#union(org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.Automaton)) of automata, so I'd guess you can easily build an automaton accepting a finite number of words.